# Парсинг столбцов Excel файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

проблема такова: Необходимо спарсить данные из Excel файла по столбацам. Парситься только один столбец, как правильно организовать второй цикл для парсинга следующих стобцов?

```
import openpyxl

path = "test.xlsx"

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
max_col = sheet_obj.max_column

for i in range(1, max_col + 1):
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(column = 2, row = i)
    print(cell_obj.value)
```

**Excel таблица**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: column - столбец, а у вас row - строки :) Нужен второй цикл по перебору row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример перебора всех ячеек:

```
import openpyxl


path = "test.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.active

for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for col in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=col)
        print(cell.value, end=' ')
    print()
```